# Coping fields from one table to another with different Scheme in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a situation I would like to handle in an optimal way without degrading performance.

I have two tables with some of the same fields. This is an example.

```
Table: Person
  case_id
  name_id
  f_name
  l_name
  comments

Table: Old_Man
  Old_man_id
  case_id
  f_name
  l_name
  comments
  age
  disable
```

Now after clicking a link(using Springs) the old_man details of a particular case must be copied into person table and only fields f_name, l_name, comments.

What is he best way to handle this situation? I am using Hibernate.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us an attempt at least...

Comment: I have changed the Person schema a bit. I have added a field Old_man_id in the person table and copy the fields related to the fields into the person table. I check for the old_man_id to see if it is an update or a create a new record in the person table from the copied fields from the Old_man Table

Comment: What I mean to say - Where is your code for the method called when you click on the button in Spring? Or do you not have any code and want someone to write it for you given the params?

Comment: I will reformat the Question and give it a better Shape